# Laravel Action App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ConcursoController@store not defined

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post, laravel-blade

I want to save some form data, and I'm Getting error.

> The Error

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ConcursoController@store not defined. (0)
```

> My Form

```
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'Admin\ConcursoController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
 <div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('company','Entidade')}}
  {{Form::text('company','',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nome da entidade aquí..'])}}
</div>
{{Form::submit('submeter', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> My Route

```
$this->group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
$this->get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
$this->resource('concursos', 'ConcursoController');
```

});

> Controller index Method

```
public function index()
{
    $concursos = Concurso::all();
    $title = 'Concursos';
    return view('admin.concursos.index',compact('title'))->with('concursos',$concursos);

}
```

> Controller Create method

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.concursos.create');

}
```

> Controller Store Method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);


    //Criar concurso
    $concurso = new Concurso;
    $concurso->title = $request->input('title');
    $concurso->body = $request->input('body');
    $concurso->save();

    return redirect('/admin/concursos')->with('Success', 'Concurso Adicionado');
}
```

> Laravel version 5.7.14

Comment: Can we see your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Probably check this file: `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ConcursoController` and see if you have a function/method called 'store'. The error is pretty straightforward that script can't find that function.

Comment: yes I have the method called STORE, see it I have added

Comment: Do you have it under `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ConcursoController` ? I see there is an additional folder `Admin` here, are you sure your this controller does not reside directly in `Controllers` folder?

Answer (score 0):

replace your form 
['route' => ['concursos.store']

like

```
{!! Form::model($transactions, ['route' => ['transaction.store'], 'method' => 'POST','class'=>"form-horizontal"]) !!}
```

Comment: Action App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ConcursoController@store not defined. (0)

Comment: have add name in your route?

Comment: like this $this->resource('concursos', 'ConcursoController')->name(''concursos");

Comment: replace your form tag with my form tag and change you route like i have suggested. in my answer i pass $transactions you have to pass variable which you need to pass from controller.